# Water feature using a BlinkM MaxM led

Tags: power, blinkm

I am making a water fountain feature and want to install a changing colour display that is variable in a laminar water jet.  The unit has to be stand alone and start when the power is applied.  The fountain is in the middle of a dam and is connected by a utility supply.  Will the BlinkM MaxM do. I am able to do basic electronics and was hoping that this unit is suitable for the job.  I am attaching acrylic rod to the LEDs as a light transmitter and this is insert into the water stream. I need bright LEDs. Can you recommend the electronics required for the job.

Doug

Comment: I fixed your formatting.

Comment: For your LEDs, how bright is "bright"?

Comment: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9738 "Luxeon rebel RGB" plus a driver board is another option.

Answer (score 1):

the [BlinkM maxm](http://thingm.com/products/blinkm-maxm.html) would be work well, but just remember you have to have a way to program it, with an Arduino or a [usb programmer](http://thingm.com/products/linkm.html) . the only other thing you would need would be a way to power it at the correct voltage.